# Amazon SNS FilterPolicy Subscription filter policies 200 per account meaning

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

AWS SNS Docs says: [Subscription filter policies: 200 per account](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/general/latest/gr/sns.html)

What does it mean exactly?

Does having 1 Topic:, with 201 subscribers that have a filter policy such has:
'{"key1":"HELLO"}' produces the "FilterPolicyLimitExceeded" error?

```
An error occurred (FilterPolicyLimitExceeded) when calling the SetSubscriptionAttributes operation: Could not complete request: filter policy quota exceeded
```

What boggles me is that such a limit is so small, like saying:
if you will be having filter policies, you are capped at 200 subscriptions for the entire account. Increasing the Quota is not the answer either when you plan to have thousands of subscribers.

Also, there's [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sns/latest/dg/subscription-filter-policy-constraints.html) to account for the filter policy "combinations", but nothing on the FilterPolicies.